Correct .NET Architecture for long running async process
I am building c# .NET 4.8.1 MVC web application which would allow the user to set up a potentially long running task to process possibly thousands of records. The user should be able to execute the task immediately or schedule it for a future date/time.  If they execute it immediately the web page should show a progress meter, that gets updated from the server as progress on the task occurs.  However, if they leave the page and come back (or come back after the scheduled task has started) I want to attach to the async process so the user can still get updated progress reports. The user should also have the option to pause, resume, or cancel the task through the UI as long as its running.
I am no expert to async architecture or programming.  Should I set up a separate WCF service to handle the backend?  How do I handle re-attaching the UI web page to the task process after its initial creation? I am storing the task details in a MS SQL Server table.  Can anyone give me some guidance on the right direction to go?

What should happen if (i.e. when) the web server decides to restart while executing a long-running process? What should happen if two or more users start different long-running processes simultaneously?

@Mark Seeman - If the web server stopped and then restarted, I guess there would be something that would check table's status column.  If status is "Processing" then it would restart the task.  I am keeping a log of activity in the database as well, and so it should be able to filter out records that have already been processed. Two or more users should be able to set up, manage, and execute multiple long running processes simultaneously.

I can see from your description that your needs may only need the database and the application itself to complete. This kind of real-time notification class can consider SqlDependency.

There is no easy and reliable way to do this without splitting the task into multiple chunks. So each step of the operation must be a separate task. And all chunks together essentially represent a single distributed transaction. So this is similar to the Saga pattern, except all actions are performed by a single service.

So you need to store the transaction state information in the same database. The state of the operation should be marked inside the same database transaction that performs the current stage changes. And in case the operation is canceled, you need to perform reverse operations to the stages already made.
The transaction state can obviously be read from the database by a separate query. Cancellation of the operation can also be marked in the database by a separate query.
As a bonus, you'll be able to continue the operation after a technical glitch.

The long running task will actually send out texts and/or emails.  So there is no reverse operations to worry about.  Cancelling the task would simply stop the process so it doesn't send a communication to someone further down in the list.  Would you still recommend the same architecture? If so, are you thinking about a WCF Service with different methods: 1) Run task, 2) Process one record, 3) Task Progress; 4) Stop Task; 5) Pause Task; 6) Restart Task ?

As I understand, you anyway want to mark processed records in the database. Therefore, you will still need to split the operation into chunks to be able to mark records immediately after processing. And so you still need to access the database after each chunk.
So controlling the operation is better done through the database status fields, checking them after each chunk. I'm not familiar with WCF specifically, but one way or another you will have to run separate queries for all the required control methods.

You might want to look into the Saga design pattern, perhaps leveraging the Saga features of NServiceBus. Such a framework does much of the heavy lifting for you in terms of making sure that the process runs, even if servers temporarily go down, and you need to resume the long-running process on a different machine. It also handles synchronization in server farms.
You could have each Saga emit events or otherwise communicate status updates so that you can implement a progress bar.
